# hive query is not working properly

Tags: hive

I have created hive table loading data from another table when i execute the query its starting but dint produce any results

```
CREATE TABLE fact_orders1 (order_number String, created timestamp, last_upd timestamp)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS ORC;
```

> OK Time taken: 0.188 seconds

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE fact_orders1 SELECT * FROM fact_orders;
```

> Query ID = hadoop_20151230051654_78edfb70-4d41-4fa7-9110-fa9a98d5405d
>   Total jobs = 1 Launching Job 1 out of 1 Number of reduce tasks is set
>   to 0 since there's no reduce operator Starting Job =
>   job_1451392201160_0007, Tracking URL =
>   http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1451392201160_0007/ Kill
>   Command = /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.1/bin/hadoop job  -kill
>   job_1451392201160_0007

Answer (score 0):

You have no output from query because there is no data stored in it. I assume you use default metastore under `/user/hive/warehouse` so what you need to do is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/path/on/hdfs/to/data' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE fact_orders1;
```

That should work.

Also edit your query for table creation adding the `LOCATION` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE fact_orders1 (order_number String, created timestamp, last_upd timestamp)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION /user/hive/warehouse/fact_orders1;
```

In case if you want to use the data outside the hive metastore you need to use [external tables](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables)